# displaying count values as two different columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have data in a MySQL table in the following format. I want to retrieve the count in two different conditions as shown in the query below, I want to combine these queries into a single one, by which I mean I would like the first query result in one column and second query result in another column, as so:

Expected output:

```
   count      totalcount
   --------------------------
   3          6
```

Queries:

```
 select count(*) as count from entries where 
 date between '2014-08-12' and '2014-08-14';

 select count(*) as totalcount from entries ;
```

Data in mysql table:

```
  id          date
  ------------------------
  1           2014-08-14
  2           2014-08-13
  3           2014-08-12
  4           2014-08-11
  5           2014-08-10
  6           2014-08-09
```

sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faeb26/6

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(date between '2014-08-12' and '2014-08-14'), count(*) as totalcount from entries ;
```

The boolean expression in `SUM()` equals to true or false, 1 or 0. Therefore just use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the two queries together:

```
select count(*) as count, b.totalcount from entries, 
  (select count(*) as totalcount from entries) b 
where date between '2014-08-12' and '2014-08-14';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(c) as count, sum(tc) as totalcount
 from (select count(*) as c , 0 as tc from entries where date between '2014-08-12' and '2014-08-14'
        union all
       select 0 as c, count(*) as tc from entries)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple combine to result in on other `select` query try this

```
SELECT (select count(*) as count from entries where 
 date between '2014-08-12' and '2014-08-14'
) as count, (select count(*) as totalcount from entries) as totalcount;
```

[**DEMO LINK**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faeb26/20/0)